# Code Assist not working in new notebooks

Tags: front-end

All I remember doing is changing cell format type (preferences>evaluation>Input and Output) back and forth. Now even when I close and reopen, I cannot get Code Assist to show up. It works fine in existing files, and when I copy and paste from here, but in a completely blank file it does not appear.

I am running V10.4

Comment: Cell["as", "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.711853778736206*^9, 3.711853778812235*^9}}]

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previewing cell contents (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and noticing a lack of `BoxData` may give a clue that the cell is not in a `StandardForm`.

It can be confirmed/checked by going to menu `Cell / Convert To` too.

Not sure if this is emphasized anywhere in docs (link appreciated) but syntax highlighting/code assist is available only in `StandardForm` representation.

You can switch it back via mentioned menu or by pressing <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

If the problem is not localized to a specific notebook/cell check if `DefaultFormatType` options is not set to `InputForm` for affected objects.

Comment: Yep, correct. Can I make it default to StandardForm?

Comment: n/m found it http://support.wolfram.com/kb/28318 http://support.wolfram.com/kb/34575

Comment: @jamesson good you've figured it out, sorry for the delay.